# initial value to eeprom variable

Tags: c, build, atmega, microprocessors, eeprom

Hi I'm a beginner in the C Language. when I Initial value to UL variable it give me -1 at first ? how can I Initial value to eeprom variable ?

```
    eeprom int UL = 1;
    eeprom struct User user[10];
```

Comment: All I saw was pages and pages of 'lcd*'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, which actually contains multiple questions. Please post separate questions for each issue. Try to reduce your problem to a [example].

Comment: You should clean the question, I think there's a lot of code that is not necessary, so people don't feel like reading all that :( also keep only one question. This seems like a easy to improve question , do so and people will be motivated to help :)